# Pass variables into Terraform IAM Policy Document

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Editing This Question.

I'm using Terraform `v0.12.9` and I'm trying to conditionally create bucket policies with the custom policy stored as an IAM policy document.

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "my_policy" {
  statement {
    sid     = "IPALLOW"
    effect  = "Deny"
    actions = ["s3:*"]
    resources = [
      "arn:aws:s3:::${var.my_bucket}/*",
      "arn:aws:s3:::${var.my_bucket}"
    ]
    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["*"]
    }
    condition {
      test     = "NotIpAddress"
      variable = "aws:SourceIp"
      values = [
        "${concat(var.ip_one,
        var.ip_two,
        var.ip_three)}"
      ]
    }
  }

}
```

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "my-bucket-policy" {
  count  = length(var.buckets)
  bucket = element(values(var.buckets[count.index]), 0)
  policy = (
    element(values(var.buckets[count.index]), 0) == "bar_bucket" ?
    data.aws_iam_policy_document.my_policy.json : <<POLICY
  {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "HTTP",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "*",
    REST OF POLICY REDACTED
    POLICY
   )
 }


}
```

However this fails and throws an error

```
Inappropriate value for attribute "values": element 0: string required.
```

But when I hardcode the ip addresses in the policy like this,

`["100.0.0.100","100.0.0.101","100.0.0.102/24","100.0.0.103/24","100.0.0.104"]`

It works.

Is there a way to pass the IP addresses as a variable in the IAM policy document?

I've tried `jsonencode` on the values, but it add a bunch of `\` which doesn't work.

These are what the variables look like.

```
variable "ip_one" {
  type = list(string)
  default = [
    "100.0.0.100",
    "100.0.0.101"
  ]
}

variable "ip_two" {
  type = list(string)
  default = [
    "100.0.0.102/24",
    "100.0.0.103/24"
  ]
}

variable "ip_three" {
  type = list(string)
  default = [
    "100.0.0.104"
  ]
}
```

Comment: You should ***really*** not create the policies as JSON but instead use `data "aws_iam_policy_document"` blocks, see e.g. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_policy

Comment: @luk2302 I've tried using the `"aws_iam_policy_document"` block as well, but it throws an error.

Comment: Try `values = concat(var.ip_one,
        var.ip_two,
        var.ip_three)`

Comment: @luk2302 I tried this already, but it throws an error `Inappropriate value for attribute "values": element 0: string required.`

Comment: Can you add the variable definitions to the question?

Comment: @MarkoE I've added the variables. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see it, there are a couple of problems:

1. The IPs have to have the subnet mask as well, i.e., you cannot mix IP addresses with and without subnet mask. For example, in `ip_one` you are using `100.0.0.100` while in `ip_two` you have `100.0.0.102/24`.
2. The variables are already lists of strings, so concatenating lists will create a list and then `values` is supposed to be a list as well.

What I would suggest is using a local variable for any value manipulation and then using the local variable in the `values` argument. So you could do the following:

```
locals {
  ips = concat(var.ip_one, var.ip_two, var.ip_three)
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "my_policy" {
  statement {
    sid     = "IPALLOW"
    effect  = "Deny"
    actions = ["s3:*"]
    resources = [
      "arn:aws:s3:::${var.my_bucket}/*",
      "arn:aws:s3:::${var.my_bucket}"
    ]
    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["*"]
    }
    condition {
      test     = "NotIpAddress"
      variable = "aws:SourceIp"
      values = local.ips
    }
  }

}
```

Also, if you want to limit access to only a set of IPs or subnets, you should definitely consider adding the subnet mask to IPs in `ip_one` and `ip_three`. If you do not do that, the access will probably be allowed from the IP addresses you do not want to allow access from.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like

```
 values = [
 join(",", concat(var.ip_one,
 var.ip_two,
 var.ip_three))
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work either. 
This throws the error.
`The true and false result expressions must have consistent types. The given
expressions are object and string, respectively.`